# Quantlib CallableBond.cpp in Examples, has some one been able to compile and execute it?

Tags: c++, quantlib

I tried to use the Quantlib Example CallableBond.cpp but an error occur while the run with the check_delete first with the nullCalendar in the example, than when I changed the null calendar by a defined one I got another check_delete error with the Handle.

I manage to use the library for some fixed Rate bond example, and it worked fine but when I tried a FixedRateCallableBond bond I got those errors.

has some one worked on that example? Is it a problem with the version? (I am using 1.11) or something wrong that could happened while the installation?

Comment: I believe it is related to the boost I am using I tried 1.49.0 and 1.53.0, is there a particular one for quantlib?

Comment: A more recent Boost is probably better. The code has been tested with the latest.  Anyway: what operating system and compiler are you using? Did you change the .cpp file, or is it the released version?

Comment: I am using QT creator under Linux, the compiler for c++ is a gcc.

I didn't change the code, I am using the released version.

So if there is something wrong its either with my installation/boost version, or with how I link the library to the project, for the last one I just added the library as an external one,  and the compiler doesn't complain, the errors occurs while the run.

Comment: For the installation of the library I followed the indication on the website so:
unzip-> cd quantlib_directory-> ./configure  --with-boost-include=BOOST_PATH/include --with-boost-lib=BOOST_PATH/lib/ --prefix=LOCAL_PATH/   -> make -> make install,
for the test I took the code from Bond.cpp put it in my 'empty' main.cpp

Comment: This is probably not the most convenient place to go back and forth and try to diagnose the problem. I suggest you post on the QuantLib mailing list (you'll also reach more people there).

Comment: Thanks I will post it there

Comment: I solved the problem
I installed quantlib with a relatively new boost version 1.6.0, I had to link my project to the 'same' version of boost (1.6.0) too.